# Ubuntu 12.04 shutdown problem

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

I am using a Dell Inspiron 3521 series, with dual boot (Wndows7 and Ubuntu 12.04). Since 2 days, I am encountering a shutdown problem. When I shut down Ubuntu, it returns to login screen. What can be the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Once it gets rebooted and retuerns to the login screen. Login through the root and use the below command,

```
shutdown -h now
```

This will helps to shutdown the machine.

Comment: Every time I shutdown, should I type this command ?

Comment: Yes type the command in the Terminal.

Comment: You can also use 'sudo poweroff' command...

Comment: My Ubuntu 12.04 is running in 2D mode. Many features will not be available. what is the solution ?

Comment: if i wrote C/C++ programs, how should i compile those programs ? and in which dir i find those programmes?